# Sublime Text autocomplete plugin for C++?

Tags: c++, autocomplete, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm trying to have the autocomplete feature on Sublime Text by using c++ libraries. I use very often EIGEN for example, but there is no autocomplete for functions inside this library. How can I somehow export the library to let sublime know about all the functions and methods I could use within this library?

Answer (score 11):

I use the package [EasyClangComplete](https://github.com/niosus/EasyClangComplete) to auto-complete C++ code. And it works fine.

You can install this package using `Package Control`. It is easy to set it up, a working setting is as follows:

```
{  "common_flags" : [
    // some example includes
    "-I/usr/include",
    "-I$project_base_path/src",
    // this is needed to include the correct headers for clang
    "-I/usr/local/lib/clang/4.0.1/include",   ],   "cpp_flags" : [
    "-std=c++11",
    "-Wall"   ], 
   "errors_style": "phantoms", 
   "hide_default_completions": true,
   "progress_style": "ColorSublime", 
   "show_type_info": false,
}
```

Comment: As the person who has written EasyClangComplete, I would add to this answer, that this setup looks slightly arbitrary as it hardcodes the version of clang. The plugin will work much better if you would be just using cmake, then no additional configuration is generally needed.

Comment: Nowadays I didn't have to do any configuration at all, it just worked for me as soon as I installed it. Good job.

Comment: Are the above settings to be put in `preferences.sublime-settings`?