# How could I get Code::Blocks to show errors as I type for C programs?

Tags: c, ide, codeblocks

I would have thought this would be on by default, don't we pretty much all want that in an IDE.. I've checked all over it's settings for this.
If you could suggest a plugin for Sublime Text to have this ability too, that would be great. My guess is it's all pretty language specific, I know there is Ensime for Scala developers.

Comment: Are there really C or C++ IDEs doing this? Sounds very... Visual Basic. Which is not a compiled language. At any rate I don't think you'd want this, since it would lag down the IDE. Code completion is bad enough - I have yet to find an IDE which can keep up with the (lousy) speed of human fingers.

Comment: @Lundin it could show *at least parse errors* :P

Comment: @Lundin what you said sounds pretty surprising, I was under the impression that most people who write any programs that aren't tiny would prefer basic IDE features (with this feature being one of them).

Comment: @thinkvitamin the problem is that usually any such ide functionality would need to run the entire compile step which would make it *sloow*. For example JDT in Eclipse.

Comment: Oh. Well it sounds like Ensime with Sublime Text is pretty smart about it, in that it checks for syntax errors at the right times and doesn't seem to slow it down (much, at least).

Comment: @Lundin - People who use Visual Studios have raved about IntelliSense for years.  Recently, even National Instruments has started to put some IntelliSense features into their C compiler (CLANG based compiler in an NI specific LabWindows/CVI IDE).  I have used CodeCompletion in Code Blocks, and it in no way impedes my progress. Of course my typing speed since I've been programming has deteriorated to a dismal value.  So, there is that.

Answer (score 1):

First, your second question: *...a plugin for Sublime Text to have this ability too.*  There is a discussion *[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40730405/sublime-text-autocomplete)* about that.

The closest thing to IntelliSense for Code::Blocks (that I am aware of) is a feature called *[Code Completion](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Code_Completion_plugin)*.

It provides a symbols browser for your projects and *code-completion* inside the editor. During code-completion, a system of symbols is used to identify the type associated with tokens.

It works with C & C++.

If your version of Code::Blocks is reasonably recent, this feature is already installed.  Settings->Editor... will popup a dialog.  On the left slide menu, you will see the glyph for Code Completion:

[image]

Once there, these options are available for you to select:
[image]

Note, there are other items in this same slide menu that may be of interest to you, such as *Occurrences Highlighting*, *SpellChecker*, etc.